# Laravel Socialite and Office365: InvalidArgumentException in Manager.php line 90: Driver [microsoft] not supported

Tags: php, laravel, driver, office365

So I definitely can't wrap my head around this one. I'm following a Laravel 5.2 tutorial here.

http://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-facebook-login.html#.V2gUIrgrJPY

And getting the error listed above in the title. My routes look like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if(Auth::check()) return view('auth/register');
    return view('auth/login');
});

Route::get('/redirect', 'MailAuthController@redirect');
Route::get('/callback', 'MailAuthController@callback');
```

Controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Socialite;

class MailAuthController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function redirect()
      {
          return \Socialite::with('microsoft')->redirect();
      }

    public function callback()
      {
          // when microsoft calls with token
      }

    public function user()
      {

      }
}
```

And services.php looks like this:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Third Party Services
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
    | as Stripe, Mailgun, Mandrill, and others. This file provides a sane
    | default location for this type of information, allowing packages
    | to have a conventional place to find your various credentials.
    |
    */

    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],

    'mandrill' => [
        'secret' => env('MANDRILL_SECRET'),
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'key' => env('SES_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],

    'sparkpost' => [
        'secret' => env('SPARKPOST_SECRET'),
    ],

    'stripe' => [
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    ],

    'microsoft' => [
        'client_id' => env('MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('http://localhost:8000/callback'),
    ],

];
```

And other than that I have no idea where I might be going wrong. Light my way!

Comment: You are trying with Microsoft. But the error says, "Driver [microsoft] not supported". Also as per Socialite documentation, Socialite currently supports authentication with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google, GitHub and Bitbucket.

Comment: So then how does one create a custom driver such that it could support Microsoft?

Comment: Did you ever figure this ut? @SeanCorbett

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using the [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/) provider from the [Socialite Providers](http://socialiteproviders.github.io/) package.

Pull in the Microsoft-Graph provider via your `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
    ...

    "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
    "socialiteproviders/microsoft-graph": "dev-master"
},
```

Run `composer update`.

Next, add the connection credentials to `config/services.php`:

```
...

'graph' => [
    'client_id'     => 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'redirect'      => 'https://my-app.dev',
],
```

*Note: if committing `config/services.php` to a public repo, extract these values to your .env file and reference them via the [env helper method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-env);

In `config/app.php` add the `SocialiteProviders/Generators` service provider to the `providers` array:

```
'providers' => [
    ...

    /*
    * Package Service Providers...
    */
    Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,

    // This is a dependency of the socialiteproviders/microsoft-graph provider, and will be installed with the provider via it's composer.json file
    SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class,
```

Register the `Socialize` facade (also in `config/app.php`):

```
'aliases' => [
    ...

    'Socialize' => 'Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite',

],
```

Register an event listener in `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php`:

```
protected $listen = [
    ...

    'SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled' => [
        'SocialiteProviders\Graph\GraphExtendSocialite@handle'
    ],
];
```

Create your controller to handle the requests:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Socialize;

class AuthController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{

    /**
     * Redirect the user to the Graph authentication page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialize::with('graph')->redirect();

    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from graph.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Socialize::with('graph')->user();

        // $user->token;
    }
}
```

Finally add your routes in `routes/web.php`:

```
<?php

Route::get('auth/graph', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/graph/callback','Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. this was most helpful ever

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still arrives here with the same error, but using the [SocialiteProviders Microsoft provider](https://socialiteproviders.com/Microsoft) already:
Check if you have set up the library correctly.

1. Make sure to install `socialiteproviders/microsoft` from composer
2. Add the SocialiteProviders Manager to your `config/providers.php`: `\SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class`
3. Add the event listener to your `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php`:

   ```php
   \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
       [SocialiteProviders\Microsoft\MicrosoftExtendSocialite::class, 'handle'],
   ],
   ```

The last step is important, and what caused the error for me, because I didn't understand the event listener is required (and not just an optional way to extend the provider).

Answer (score 0):

So this might seem obvious but both in my case and judging from the info provided in the question, this step is also missing. I changed from the current Microsoft to the Graph and still got the same error, however I then realized this error happens when the Driver is not registered in the service provider. Make sure you are using the same spelling of the service provider in vendor and that you include the Service provider, in my case:

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Providers;
    
    use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
    
    class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * The event to listener mappings for the application.
         *
         * @var array<class-string, array<int, class-string>>
         */
        protected $listen = [
            Registered::class => [
                SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
            ],
    
            \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
                // ... other providers
/*--- I forgot this --->*/\SocialiteProviders\Graph\GraphExtendSocialite::class.'@handle',
            ],
    
        ];
    
        /**
         * Register any events for your application.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            //
        }
    
        /**
         * Determine if events and listeners should be automatically discovered.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function shouldDiscoverEvents()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This added worked with microsoft graph, driver: "graph" from: https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Microsoft-Graph

I never got to try with the listed driver "Microsoft" on socialiteproviders.com
and as of the time of this writing Graph was removed from that website, however all I care is that it works and it worked as expected!